# System.IO.IOException while WriteLineAsync

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, ioexception

I got an "System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'output.txt' because it is being used by another process.'" when I try to await method that includes an WriteLineAsync from StreamWriter.

```
while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
            {
                outputPath = "output.txt";
                await WriteLine(outputPath, line);
            }
        }
    }

    static async Task WriteLine(string path, string line)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new(path, true))
        {
            await writer.WriteLineAsync(line);
        }
    }
```

When I try to await WriteLine I got an IOException. But whithout it reads and writes file till the end. How does it work?

Comment: But I'm reading one file and writing to another

Comment: Are you disposing the reader with `using`?

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, I disposing the reader with `using`. I have no issues with reader or its file. When I try to write data (to a different file) I randomly have a IOException. But it appears when i use "await" in line: `await WriteLine(outputPath, line);`. But when I write: `WriteLine(outputPath, line)`; no exception appears.

Comment: I run your code, and it completed without exception. Maybe you are opening "output.txt" somewhere else? How do you create the reader? Is it another file?

Answer (score 0):

Calling .Close() directly on the stream writer worked for me

```
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText($"{currentLogFileName}"))
            {
                await writer.WriteLineAsync(contentToWrite);
                writer.Close();  // <-- I had to add this line
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            // handle any other IO exceptions
        }
```